# Error Code when script tries to import All Day Event to Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have been using the same script to import appointments to Calendar for 2 years with no issues. All of a sudden today, I am getting an error code that reads TypeError: **Cannot find function createAllDayEvent in object Calendar. (line 35, file "Code")**

Why is this happening?? We use this script to schedule company deliveries, so I really need it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

This is the script I have been using...

```
function importCalendar() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = range.getValues();
    var calId = "CALENDAR ID HERE";
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var startDate = row[3];  // Fourth column
    var title = row[1];           // Second column
    var location = row[2];
    var description = row[4];
    var id = row[6];              // Seventh column == eventId
    var advancedArgs ={description: description, location: location};
    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
    }
    if (!event) {
      //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(startDate), advancedArgs).getId(); This is the row with the error.
      row[6] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
    }
    else {
      Utilities.sleep(5000);
      event.setTitle(title);
      event.setDescription(description);
      event.setLocation(location);
      // event.setTime(tstart, tstop); // cannot setTime on eventSeries.
      // ... but we CAN set recurrence!
      var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
      event.setRecurrence(recurrence, new Date(startDate));
    }
    debugger;
    }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
    range.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: This was actually a google issue. It works again. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this thread: [Cannot find function createEvent (or createAllDayEvent) in object Calendar. (Google Spreadsheet App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517231/cannot-find-function-createevent-or-createalldayevent-in-object-calendar-goo). Make sure that yout `startDate` variable has the right format.

> if you are not sure about the 'date' variable being actually a date
>   you could use
>
> ```
>   cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date), {description:desc,location:loc});
> ```
>
> that said, it is quite easy to check with the logger
>
> ```
> Logger.log(date)
> ```
>
> should return a date value in the form `Tue Sep 18 03:00:00 PDT 2012`

Additional reference: [Google script google sheet to calendar TypeError: Cannot find function createEvent in object Calendar. (line 18, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988894/google-script-google-sheet-to-calendar-typeerror-cannot-find-function-createeve)